# jquery rotation which can rotate table html elements

Tags: jquery

I have table with some data. Table has 40 nested tds like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
xxx
</td>
<td>
xxx
</td>
<td>
xxx
</td>
...
</tr>
</table>
```

now i am looking for some jquery rotation plugin which will rotate this tds. Does anyone know any good jquery rotation plugin which can rotate table tds? And when you gove over td with mouse it will stop, I am googling but i can not found anything like this.

example

| xxx1 | | xxx2 || xxx3 || xxx4 || xxx5 || xxx6 || xxx7 || xxx8 || xxx9 || xxx10 |

this text will rotate like

| xxx11 | | xxx12 || xxx13 || xxx14 || xxx15 || xxx16 || xxx17 || xxx18 || xxx19 || xxx20 |

and so on...

hope you underastand what i am searching for

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll"? You just want a scrollbar to be able to navigate left and right through the table? Or you want that, but if you position the mouse near the edge it will scroll automatically? Or what?

Comment: Sorry i mean rotation... i want that 40 tds (text with image) will rotate over and over again. In main page i can show only 10 tds so i need to rotate all 40, 60 or maybe more tds too see it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like rotation (like, drawing text at a 45 degree angle). I think the term you're looking for is "Scrolling marquee".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:  http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Try putting your table inside that jquery `<marquee>` element

Answer (score 2):

I would use a plugin, like the one mentioned by dthorpe.  If you want to build your own, you can start here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/Yde6w/

```
var w = $('#data').width();
$('#data').animate({left: -1*w}, w*10);
```

That will get it to scroll, you just have to restart the animation once it completes.  It's very simple to encapsulate that logic into a jQuery extension function... but at that point, we might as well use a plugin that has already been tested.

Comment: Cool man, Can you rotate them over and over like true Marquee ?

Comment: @SurjitSamra: yeah, just have to put it in a loop. The extra lines of code is for caching: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/Yde6w/2/